# write data within single qutations and dowble quotations

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written value data within single quotations and wanted to add var value but when I see that within out it is showing out put as

```
<a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(103, " all',="" '%');'="">%</a>
//Out put should be like this 
<a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(103, 'all', '%');">%</a>
```

Can anyone help me out with this here is my code which I have written to show the link

```
function getCompanyRatesGraph(val, timeFrame) {
    $('.load_dt_grph').show();
$.ajax({
    url     : "<?php echo site_url('company/'.$companies['id']); ?>",
    type    : "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data    : "id=" + val + "&timeFrame=" + timeFrame,
    success : function (data) {
            if (timeFrame === "day") {
                make_chart(data);
            } else {
                make_chart(data);
            }

            var companies_id = ]<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>";

            var data_per = "<a onclick='getCompanyRatesGraph('"+companies_id+"', '"+timeFrame+"', '%');'>%</a>";
            $('.per').html(data_per);

            $('.pkr').html('<a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>, "'+timeFrame+'", "Pkr");">Pkr</a>');
            if(data.length < 1) {
                $(".amcharts-chart-div").html("<h3 style='text-align: center;'>Today's Data is not available.</h3>");
            }
        $('.load_dt_grph').hide();
    }
});
}
```

So my question raises here what I am doing wrong here am I not suing quotations properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var companies_id = "<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>";
var data_per = "<a onclick=\"getCompanyRatesGraph("+companies_id +",'"+timeFrame+"', '%');\">%</a>";
```

This will work

Comment: Finally this worked for me this is the output now <a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(298,'all', '%');">%</a> My question raised tis how is this doen why you used \"

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
var companies_id = "<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>";

data_per = "<a onclick='getCompanyRatesGraph('"+companies_id+"', '"+timeFrame+"', '%');'>%</a>";
            $('.per').html(data_per);
```

Comment: here is the out put I am getting <a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(" 298',="" 'all',="" '%');'="">%</a>

Comment: Its seems to be something wrong with your other code, can you share me your full code?

Comment: Try this:

`var companies_id = "<?php echo $companies['id'] ?>";
data_per = "<a onclick='getCompanyRatesGraph("+companies_id+", "+timeFrame+", %)'>%</a>";
$('.per').html(data_per);`

Comment: just to check when I write like this data_per = "<a onclick='getCompanyRatesGraph(%);'>%</a>"; then it is working fnine

Comment: <a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(298, all, %)">%</a> this is the output now

Comment: The reason is your are using single quotes outside and inside the function, the code get the value when its completed inside the single quotes. That is why I added code with removing inner single quotes.
Is this output working fine?

`<a onclick="getCompanyRatesGraph(298, all, %)">%</a>`